# crawl URLs based on their priorities in StormCrawler

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am working on a crawler based on the StormCrawler project. I have a requirement to crawl URLs based on their priorities. For example, I have two types of priority: HIGH, LOW. I want to crawl HIGH priority URLs as soon as possible before LOW URLs. I need a method for handling the above problem in the crawler. How can I handle this requirement in Apache Storm and StormCrawler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Elasticsearch as a backend, you can configure the spouts to sort the URLs within a bucket by whichever field you want. The fields [are sorted by ascending order](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/persistence/AggregationSpout.java#L146) so you should store a value in the metadata of 0 for high and 1 for low and specify the key name in the conf *es.status.bucket.sort.field*. (Note that HIGH and LOW as values would work as well).

The default values in the [ES archetype](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/es-conf.yaml#L59) are

> es.status.bucket.sort.field:
>
> - "nextFetchDate"
> - "url"

you should keep the nextFetchDate so that URLs with the same priority are sorted by it and have for instance

> es.status.bucket.sort.field:
>
> - "metadata.priority"
> - "nextFetchDate"
> - "url"

Note that this won't affect how the buckets are sorted, just the order within them.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Nioche. Your approach is really interesting. Is there any way to control the processing order of tuples inside the crawler base on their priorities?

Comment: In some situations, maybe lots of LOW priority tuples have been emitted before we adding a HIGH priority one from the Spout.

Comment: In addition, We are using Apache Solr for indexing of crawler results and feeding the URLs. Is there a similar approach for Apache Solr backend?

Comment: I assume you mean that the LOW and HIGH could belong to the same host and that the HIGH would get stuck in the internal queues of the fetcher. If you keep the number of URLs from each bucket low, this shouldn't be an issue. You could also have 2 FetcherBolts and add a custom bolt to redirect the tuples to one or the other based on their priority value.

Comment: The SOLR module is quite behind the ES one and the custom sorting is currently not available. This shouldn't be too hard to implement thought and would be a valuable contribution to the project if you feel like it.

Comment: What happened if I add query.setSort() statement to the SOLR query?

Comment: I think sorting in a bucket can not solve my problem. Because it sorts inside a bucket partially. But I need to emit tuples to the topology in sorted manner.

Comment: Whats is the meaning of bucket in SOLR or ES spouts?